# How can I change the name of a parameter in an array.map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, array.prototype.map

I have a little doubt. How can I make the marker parameter change to marker1, marker2, marker3 depending on how many elements are in the map?

i have this but i want that for each element of the map there is a +1 for each marker

```
            {teams.map((team) =>
            <pointer
            marker={marker1}
```

for example, that the first element of the .map has the parameter {marker1}, the second {marker2}, the third {marker3} and so on

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how would you like to handle the clicks, but in general, you can use the `index` of the `team` when mapping the `teams` array.

[More about `.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Example:

```
teams.map((team, index) => <pointer marker={`marker-${index + 1}`} />)
```

Or if you prefer to pass the value to click event directly:

```
teams.map((team, index) => (
  <pointer onClick={() => handleClick(`marker-${index + 1}`)} />
))
```

When doing the `.map()` ensure to also set a unique `key` on the mapped component.

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

if markers are some variables one solution can be that you can make an array of variables of markers like `let markersArray = [marker1 , marker2 , ...]` and then use the index in the map method to index the marker variable in each loop like

```
{
    teams.map((team,index) =>
        <pointer
         marker={markersArray[index]}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Let your array is 
**const markersArray = [....]** 

In jsx, 
 markersArray.map((team, index) => {
     <pointer
         marker={markersArray[index]}
})
```

you can identify the object on basis of the index.